# React state function is using outdade state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a state that holds a function and this function use another state value but, when I change this second state value its value is not reflected in first state function.

I know that React is using an old version of my function but how can I solve this? Should I use `useEffect` to update the function if the second state changes? Should I use `useCallback`? I'm a little confused on this and when I should use one or another.

Here's an example of my code:

```
type StepsActionType = {
  onStep: () => void;
  ... other props
}
type StepsType = {
  hint: string
  target: number
}

...
// stepsProps needs to be an empty object until `onReady` is called
const [stepsProps, setStepsProps] = React.useState<Partial<StepsActionType>>({});
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState<number>(0);

const availableSteps = useRef<StepsType[]>([{
  hint: 'first step',
  target: 10
},{
  hint: 'second step',
  target: 20
}]).current
const {
  hint,
  target
} = availableSteps[ currentStep ]

useEffect(() => {
  // this is called after data is fetched from server
  onReady()
}, [])

function onReady() {
  console.log("now ready");
  setStepsProps({
    onStep: () => {
      console.log('target', target)
      ... some other calcs
    }
  });
}

function increaseStep() {
  setCurrentStep((current) => {
    const next = current + 1;
    console.log("next step", next);
    return next;
  });
}

function handleStep() {
  stepsProps.onStep?.();
}

return <>
  step hint: { hint }
</>
```

When my app is mounted it sets a step handler function to `stepsProps` state but if the step is increased calling `increaseStep` the step handler keeps saying I'm on step 0 instead of 1 and step `target` is not updated.

[Here's](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hooks-confusion-prr37t?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A7%2C17) a codesandbox I've made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need stepsProps to be an empty object before onRead is called.

A - You can add a state key, hasStepsProps

```
  const [hasStepsProps, setHasStepsProps] = React.useState(false);

  const stepsProps = hasStepsProps
    ? {
        onStep: function doSomethingWithTarget() {},
        // ...otherProps
      }
    : {};

    function onReady() {
      setHasStepsProps(true);
    }
```

B- Add target to stepsProps

```
  const [stepsProps, setStepsProps] = React.useState({});

  function onReady() {
    setStepsProps({
      target,
      onStep: function doSomethingWithTarget() {},
      // ...otherProps
    });
  }

  if (stepsProps.target !== target) {
    setStepsProps((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      onStep: function doSomethingWithTarget() {},
      target,
    }));
  }
```

C- Introduce a new state key, prevTarget

```
  const [prevTarget, setPrevTarget] = React.useState(10);
  const [stepsProps, setStepsProps] = React.useState({});


  function updateStepProps() {
    setPrevTarget(target);
    setStepsProps({
      onStep: function doSomethingWithTarget() {},
      // ...otherProps
    });
  }

  useEffect(updateStepProps, []);
  
  if (prevTarget !== target) {
    updateStepProps();
  }
```

*** Previous answer before more clarifications:

React documents suggest to avoid using useEffect to [adjust some state when a prop changes](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes)

Instead you could calculate stepsProps during rendering. Then, you wont’t need useEffect at all.

```
//...
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState(0);

const stepsProps = {
  onStep: () => console.log("current step", currentStep),
};

function increaseStep() {
  setCurrentStep((current) => {
    const next = current + 1;
    console.log("next step", next);
    return next;
  });
}

function handleStep() {
  stepsProps.onStep();
}
//...
```

If stepsProps is costly and you want to avoid calculating it on every render you could use memoization:

```
  const stepsProps = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      onStep: () => console.log("current step", currentStep),
    }),
    [currentStep, ...otherDependenciesIfNeeded]
  );
```

In case, stepsProps has bunch of different props with different dependencies, it could be calculated like below.

```
  const onStep = React.useCallback(
    () => console.log("current step", currentStep),
    [currentStep]
  );

  const stepsProps = {
    onStep,
    /// otherProps with different dependencies
  };
```

Alternatively, you might even declare onStep as handleStep directly with or without useCallback.

```
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState(0);

  function increaseStep() {
    setCurrentStep((current) => {
      const next = current + 1;
      console.log("next step", next);
      return next;
    });
  }

  const handleStep = () => console.log("current step", currentStep),
```

I have tested all the above snippets, and all work.

Comment: Your sollution works but I need `stepsProps` to be an empty object before `onRead` is called, in your example its value is already setted before app is ready

Answer (score 0):

Use setState in callback of other, And your issue is solved. There is no need to use of useEffect or useCallback like below...

```
type StepsActionType = {
  onStep: () => void;
};

//...
const [stepsProps, setStepsProps] = React.useState<Partial<StepsActionType>>(
    {}
  );
const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = React.useState<number>(0);

function onReady() {
  setStepsProps({ currentStep });
}

function increaseStep() {
  setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
}

function handleStep() {
  setStepsProps(() => {
    const current = currentStep + 1;
    setCurrentStep(current);
    return { currentStep: current };
  });
}
//...
```